I am getting this error ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False, Please help to solve it
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.utils import to_categorical

    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
    from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
    label_map = {label:num for num, label in enumerate(actions)}
    sequences, labels = [], []
    for action in actions:
    for sequence in range(no_sequences):
        window = []
        for frame_num in range(sequence_length):
            res = np.load(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), "{}.npy".format(frame_num)))`ERROR`
            window.append(res)`your text`
        sequences.append(window)
        labels.append(label_map[action])

Error occurs in the line np.load() method while loading .npy array.

The error you're encountering is due to the default security settings in NumPy that prevent loading pickled data. Allow pickle loading Add allow_pickle=True to your np.load() call:
res = np.load(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), "{}.npy".format(frame_num)), allow_pickle=True)

